# After system update snap apps not working

Tags: updates, snap, chromium

I'm using Ubuntu desktop 20.04.2 GNOME 3.36.8 x11. Recently (one month back) I updated my system and since then snap apps are not starting.

Following are some logs in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
--- ubuntu20 android-studio_android-studio.desktop[5939]: env: ‘/snap/bin/android-studio’: No such file or directory

--- ubuntu20 chromium_chromium.desktop[5990]: env: ‘/snap/bin/chromium’: No such file or directory

--- ubuntu20 gnome-system-monitor_gnome-system-monitor.desktop[5998]: env: ‘/snap/bin/gnome-system-monitor’: No such file or directory
```

I have checked the `/snap/bin` folder and all the links in there are broken. All the links are pointing to `/usr/bin/snap`, but there is no such file.

I was able to run `gnome-system-monitor` from command line, but I don't know how to start other apps. I badly need Chromium. I have created a couple of profiles which have lots of bookmarks and history.

Edit: Unable to repair snap. I logged into Windows 7 (dual boot, rarely use it). It ran a disk scan and found lots of broken files (html, php) on the `C` drive. Does this have any connection?

Comment: May be there was power loss during update...I don't remember

Comment: Hey Suresh! Paste the output of `snap list` in your question and do not forget to [format it as code](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: `snap list` command output:

Command 'snap' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install snapd

Comment: Looks like snapd is not there in your device. Let's look into your terminal history to find out what went wrong. Please copy the contents of `/home/<YOUR_USERNAME>/.bash_history` in a pastebin (like http://paste.ubuntu.com) and share the link. I'll try to go through your terminal history and try to find the issue.

Comment: [https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Bh9rzvQTF8/](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Bh9rzvQTF8/)

After update network also not working...so I tried to fix it...I have separated commands which ran after update

Comment: Hmm.. Please paste the output of `sudo apt install snapd` **in your question**.

Comment: I previously tried to run `sudo apt install snapd` ... but interrupted in the middle...I ran it again now...snap apps are running :-) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `snapd` is not there in your device. Run

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

Now, you will be able to use snap apps.